# How to build a go-jet case condition

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm working on checking whether AffectedTo field in the table is null or not, if it's null then return true, if it's not null then compare with input date.
The problem is when I tried to use Case condition, it doesn't return a boolean expression, so I can't use it with Where(). I'm new to Golang and sql builder, how do I solve this?
Here are my libraries:

```
package postgres

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "financing-offer/internal/core/entity"
    "financing-offer/internal/database"
    "financing-offer/internal/database/dbmodels/finoffer/public/enum"
    "financing-offer/internal/database/dbmodels/finoffer/public/model"
    "financing-offer/internal/database/dbmodels/finoffer/public/table"

    "github.com/go-jet/jet/v2/postgres"
    "github.com/go-jet/jet/v2/qrm"
)
```

```
func (b *BlackListSymbolRepository) GetByAffectTime(ctx context.Context, symbolId int64, affectedFrom time.Time, affectedTo time.Time) ([]entity.BlacklistSymbol, error) {
    // Create a CASE condition
    caseCondition := postgres.CASE().
        WHEN(table.BlacklistSymbol.AffectedTo.IS_NULL()).THEN(postgres.Bool(true)).
        ELSE(table.BlacklistSymbol.AffectedTo.GT(postgres.TimestampT(affectedFrom)))

    // Combine the conditions in the WHERE clause
    stm := table.BlacklistSymbol.SELECT(table.BlacklistSymbol.AllColumns).
        WHERE(
            table.BlacklistSymbol.SymbolID.EQ(postgres.Int64(symbolId)).
                AND(table.BlacklistSymbol.Status.EQ(enum.Blacklistsymbolstatus.Active)).
                AND(table.BlacklistSymbol.AffectedFrom.LT_EQ(postgres.TimestampT(affectedTo))).
                AND(caseCondition.IS_NOT_NULL()), // Use the CASE condition
        )

    dest := make([]model.BlacklistSymbol, 0)
    if err := stm.QueryContext(ctx, b.getDbFunc(ctx), &dest); err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, qrm.ErrNoRows) {
            return []entity.BlacklistSymbol{}, nil
        }
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("BlackListSymbolRepository GetByAffectTime %w", err)
    }
    return MapBlacklistSymbolsDbToEntity(dest), nil
}
```

I tried to use

```
caseCondition.IS_NOT_NULL()
```

to return a boolexpression but it just returned true since the caseCondition is already not null.